# Is there a way to create to use CreateSpyObj to create a spy of all methods in a class?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for my Angular app and I'm learning about how to use spies.

Currently, every service that my component uses, I have to write something like this

```
let fakeMyService = jasmine.createSpyObj('fakeMyService', ['method1', 'method2']);
fakeMyService.method1.and.returnValue(Observable.of());
fakeMyService.method2.and.returnValue(Observable.of());

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: MyService, useValue: fakeMyService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
```

Although this works, it doesn't seem like the best way to set up my spies. For one, I have to type every single function in MyService that I want to put spies in. Secondly, it's not strongly typed. So if I ever change the name, I won't know immediately and also then, I'll have to update it in every place.

Is there some sort of way where I can just specify the class and it'll automatically just return me a fake class with spies for all the methods?

So something like this

```
  let fakeMyService = jasmine.createSpyObj<MyService>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the new `spyOnAllFunctions` feature:

```
let fakeMyService = spyOnAllFunctions(MyService);
```

be aware that this is a [new feature](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/1581) and it's available only in the latest 3.x version of Jasmine.

Also be aware that this feature is not yet present in the current typing (@types/jasmine). There is a feature request about it [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/30552).

Comment: Update: it's present in the 3.3.0 version of the typings

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own function to do this:

```
function getMock(c) {
  return jasmine.createSpyObj(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c.prototype));
}
```

All you have to do now to create a spy of all methods of a class is:

```
let fakeMyService = getMock(MyFakeService);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want type checks

```
let fakeService: MyService = spyOnAllFunctions<MyService>(MyService.prototype);
fakeProductRepository.method1 = () => {
  return null
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just  SpyOn( service, method) instead but it would be best to test all methods in a service/module/factory

Comment: How is that better? Then I still have to have a spyon for every method and once again I'm putting the method as a string so it's not strongly typed.

Comment: It would allow you to only have to type in the methods you actually plan to test instead of causing errors if you do not have all the methods in the SpyObject like in your question.